# Why asarray and list react diffently?

Tags: numpy, types, difference

I'm trying to understand why :

```
 w=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,0]
 print(w[w!=0])
```

outputs : `0.2`,

while

```
 w=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,0]
 w=np.asarray(w)
 print(w[w!=0])
```

outputs : `[0.1 0.2 0.3 0.5]`, which seems more logical

So : why lists do return the second element ?

Comment: Ultimately, they react differently because they are **different** types. Much like a cat and a tiger react differently to a poke with a stick

Comment: It wasn't a surprise to know that there are two different data type. I was looking for a comprehension of WHY does list reacts by throwing the second element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `list` and an `ndarray` implement comparison differently.  In particular:

- a `list` returns a single `bool` value of `True` or `False` when compared to something else.  Clearly a list `w` is not the value `0.2` so `w != 0.2` returns `True`
- an `ndarray` implements comparison by returning an `ndarray` of booleans, representing each array element’s comparison.  Thus, `w != 0.2` returns `[True False True True]`

Thus

- for a `list`, `w[w!=0.2]` is `w[True]` and this is treated as meaning `w[1]`
- for an `ndarray` it is `w[ ndarray([True False True True]) ]` which then leverages numpy’s array indexing to return only those elements where the Boolean is `True`

Comment: This is clarifying why i can poke a cat with a stick and not a tiger ! Thanks